# Magento display configurable attribute values

Tags: magento, attributes, product

I need to display, in my homepage, the available colors of a specific configurable product. The availability is based on the stock quantity.

For example, a config. product is associated with these simple producs:

BLACK M --> quantity 5
 
BLACK S --> quantity 0
BLACK X --> quantity 3
   RED M --> quantity 10 
 
RED S --> quantity 25 
 
YELLOW XL --> quantity 0

In this case, I would like to display:

**"The available colors:
BLACK , RED "**

YELLOW is not included because its quantity is 0

I found out this php method to estimate the quantity, but I can't show the colors as I would:

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();

$myconfig = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($store->getId())->load(21765);

$ids = $myconfig->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds();

foreach ($ids as $id):

$simple = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id); 

$quantity = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simple)->getQty();

endforeach;
```

The $quantity let a conditional check for the displaying, but I need all the following part...
thanks a lot guys

Comment: I solved this topic by a Javascript method, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608678/rik) (OP) already self-answered the question.

Quote:

> I solved this topic by a Javascript method, thank you

<sub>Note: It's absolutely [OK to self-answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions/12519#12519) your own question. Please just post it as an real answer, but *not* in a question or comment. Posting as real answer helps to keep the "Unanswered" list more clear (avoids making other people wasting their time).</sub>